# How to use the PHP parser only?

Tags: codemirror

All modes for CodeMirror that I've found use PHP parser as multi parser combined with HTML and JavaScript. All these require `<?php` to start highlighting PHP.

I want to have everything in my textarea highlighted as PHP. Assume `<?php` at the beginning and ignore any further `?>`.
Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"text/x-php"` as your `mode` option.